# I don't understand the error i get in this programming code

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error, and I am using VS 2013. I downloaded the source code for MUD ROM 2.4b6 and when i go to compile this is what i get.

Error   5   error C2109: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

the error is for the spec_table in:

```
fun == spec_table[cmd].function
```

and this is the code that its giving me the problem. I have absolutely no idea where to being? Btw spec_table was defined on the same file at the very top of the code. Can anyone please shed some insight?

```
/* OLC Inserted */
/*****************************************************************************
 Name:      spec_string
 Purpose:   Given a function, return the appropriate name.
 Called by: <???>
 ****************************************************************************/
char *spec_string( SPEC_FUN *fun )  /* OLC */
{
int cmd;

for ( cmd = 0; spec_table[cmd].function[0] != '\0'; cmd++ )
if ( fun == spec_table[cmd].function )
    return spec_table[cmd].name;

return 0;
}
```

the spec_table is defined at the very top of the file with this section: It is just a snippet because the whole thing is too large.

```
const   struct  spec_type    spec_table[] =
{
    {   "spec_breath_any",          spec_breath_any         },
    {   "spec_breath_acid",         spec_breath_acid        },
    {   "spec_breath_fire",         spec_breath_fire        },
    {   "spec_breath_frost",        spec_breath_frost       },
    {   "spec_breath_gas",          spec_breath_gas         },
    {   "spec_breath_lightning",    spec_breath_lightning   },
```

here is the declaration for spec_type in a header file.

```
struct spec_type
{
char *  name;           /* special function name */
SPEC_FUN *  function;       /* the function */
};
```

this is the declaration for SPEC_FUN

```
typedef bool SPEC_FUN   args( ( CHAR_DATA *ch ) );
```

this is the declaration for CHAR_DATA

```
    struct  char_data
{
CHAR_DATA *         next;
CHAR_DATA *         next_in_room;
CHAR_DATA *         master;
CHAR_DATA *         leader;
CHAR_DATA *         fighting;
CHAR_DATA *         reply;
CHAR_DATA *         pet;
MEM_DATA *          memory;
SPEC_FUN *          spec_fun;
MOB_INDEX_DATA *    pIndexData;
DESCRIPTOR_DATA *   desc;
AFFECT_DATA *       affected;
NOTE_DATA *         pnote;
OBJ_DATA *          carrying;
OBJ_DATA *          on;
ROOM_INDEX_DATA *   in_room;
ROOM_INDEX_DATA *   was_in_room;
AREA_DATA *         zone;
PC_DATA *           pcdata;
GEN_DATA *          gen_data;
bool                valid;
char *              name;
long                id;
sh_int              version;
char *              short_descr;
char *              long_descr;
char *              description;
char *              prompt;
char *              prefix;
sh_int              group;
sh_int              clan;
sh_int              sex;
sh_int              class;
sh_int              race;
sh_int              level;
sh_int              trust;
int                 played;
int                 lines;  /* for the pager */
time_t              logon;
sh_int              timer;
sh_int              wait;
sh_int              daze;
sh_int              hit;
sh_int              max_hit;
sh_int              mana;
sh_int              max_mana;
sh_int              move;
sh_int              max_move;
long                gold;
long                silver;
int                 exp;
long                act;
long                comm;   /* RT added to pad the vector */
long                wiznet; /* wiz stuff */
long                imm_flags;
long                res_flags;
long                vuln_flags;
sh_int              invis_level;
sh_int              incog_level;
long                affected_by;
sh_int              position;
sh_int              practice;
sh_int              train;
sh_int              carry_weight;
sh_int              carry_number;
sh_int              saving_throw;
sh_int              alignment;
sh_int              hitroll;
sh_int              damroll;
sh_int              armor[4];
sh_int              wimpy;
/* stats */
sh_int              perm_stat[MAX_STATS];
sh_int              mod_stat[MAX_STATS];
/* parts stuff */
long                form;
long                parts;
sh_int              size;
char*               material;
/* mobile stuff */
long                off_flags;
sh_int              damage[3];
sh_int              dam_type;
sh_int              start_pos;
sh_int              default_pos;
};
```

Comment: So how was it defined?

Comment: Looks like cmd must be a pointer or array, and you have it as an int.

Comment: `***spec_table***[cmd].function[0]` ... **really**?

Comment: Yeah, please don't do stuff like `***spec_table***`.  Is that real code?  If so, there's your problem. If not, remove it as it is confusing.

Comment: `spec_table[cmd].function[0]` - what `[0]` here supposed to mean? What type `function` member have?

Comment: It is a normal error in this situation. You are not providing any subscripting operator in your struc, and... it is a struct.

Comment: @Victor, `spec_table` is an array of structs.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is here guys?

Comment: You try to access `function`'s first element, but `function` does not seem to be an array. Could you please provide `spec_type` declaration?

Comment: spec_type is the structs name

Comment: `const struct spec_type spec_table[]` here `spec_type` is structure (type name), `spec_table` is variable name. We need `spec_type` declaration.

Comment: ok here is the declaration for spec_type it is located in a header file ill update it in post

Comment: what you posted is not a declaration of `spec_type`.

Comment: then I am not sure what you want. VS takes me to the declaration, and that is what it gives me. How would it look like?

Comment: @user3330589: Like `struct spec_type { some_type function; ... };`

Comment: If you are not comfortable with whatever language this was written in (is it really c++?), I would suggest that you don't start with cross-compiling or compiling on a much newer compiler as a starter project. There may be *many* other issues with getting this working.

Comment: ok i found it, posting it to main post

Comment: @n0rd i found the declaration for spec_type i hope this helps. Thanks for everyone trying to help me out

Comment: Now how about the definition of `SPEC_FUN`?

Comment: ok putting it into main post

Comment: and before you ask ill go ahead and put definition for SPEC_CHAR as well

Answer (score 1):

Now that we have the code we need...

```
struct spec_type
{
    char *  name;           /* special function name */
    SPEC_FUN *  function;       /* the function */
};
```

I'm assuming that `function` is a function pointer.  You cannot index into a function pointer, it makes no sense because these pointers do not poijnt to a complete type.  For example, you cannot take the `sizeof` a function type, so how would the compiler know how to get to the next element?

It would be wrong anyway; `function[0]` would never be of the type `char`. Did you mean to check the `name` field for a null character?  That would make more sense.

When you index into a pointer type, what's really going on is this:

```
p[n] = *(p + n) = *(p incremented by sizeof n bytes)
```

It looks like you're just trying to get the string representation of the function.  Try this:

```
// you should be returning a const char*, not a char*
const char *spec_string( SPEC_FUN *fun )  /* OLC */
{
    int cmd;
    static const int size = sizeof spec_table / sizeof spec_table[0];
    for (cmd = 0; cmd < size; cmd++) {
        if (fun == spec_table[cmd].function) {
            return spec_table[cmd].name;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using the knowledge now, how do we solve the original error that i get?

Comment: @user3330589: You remove `function[0]` because it makes no sense.  Did you mean to check the `name` field for a null character?  Even that makes little sense in the context of your code.

Comment: alright ill go through what you just said to make sense of things. Thanks for the help, lets see if it continues to give me the error.

Comment: @user3330589: Here, I'll write you a version that works.

Comment: well apprently it didn't want to compile when i took out the function [0] so i just took out the [0] and it isn't complaining anymore. Would it make more sense that way?

Comment: @user3330589: No.  I added a version which should work

Comment: yes that version did work.. I am sorry to keep bothering you with this, but in very plain simple english.. what did your version work and not the original?

Comment: @user3330589: No bother, it's good that you want to understand your code.  This condition makes no sense; `spec_table[cmd].function[0] != '\0'`.  What you really wanted was to compare function pointers.  So, I loop through each element of the array (`size` elements) and compare the pointers. When I find a match, I return the string (`name`).

Comment: Alright that piece of code worked, but the compiler is giving me a new  error from the spec_string

error C2373: 'spec_string' : redefinition; different type modifiers

Comment: @user3330589: Sounds like you have two definitions for that function because you copied mine in and didn't remove yours. That is a no-no.  One definition rule.

Comment: so i would have to go to where spec_string is defined and replace it?

Comment: ahhhhaaa that worked, i found where spec_string was defined and added const char to the existing char