# Compiling Source Code with VS

Tags: c++

i am trying to compile this source code, and the first error i get is from this piece of code saying that 'bool' is undefined.. Which makes no sense, because it i don't see anything wrong with that? Can anyone shed some light? If you need something else from the code just let me know. Thanks!

```
typedef bool SPEC_FUN   args( ( CHAR_DATA *ch ) );
```

Comment: What is the `args` thing for?

Comment: What are `SPEC_FUN` and `CHAR_DATA` as well? Are these macros?

Comment: Does the file have a .c extension? There is no bool type in C.

Comment: What version of VS? Old MS C or C++ compiler may not have `bool`.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233088/i-dont-understand-the-error-i-get-in-this-programming-code

Comment: Code appears to be from here (or something related):
https://github.com/demortes/Assault-3.0/blob/master/src/typedefs.h

Comment: And the code has a lot of references to half a dozen different flavours of Unix, but none for Windows, which probably means it won't trivially compile on Windows.

Comment: (There are of course lots of other copies of Mud out there - the point being that this code is not portable to Windows without a reasonable amount of work).

Comment: To overcome this particular error you could define `typedef int bool;` (like it does several lines above for example in the AIX version). But I expect that within 5 lines you'll find something else that doesn't compile, and that isn't so easily resolved.